# Can't set project in Cloud Natural Language API

Tags: python, google-cloud-nl

I'm using the api sample as found [here](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/sentiment-tutorial).

Running `gcloud config list` shows my default project as `project = multichoice-insights`

Important extract of the code shows that I get the default credentials:

```
  credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default().create_scoped(
  ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'],
)
```

However, when I try and use the api, I get the error message:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting 
https://language.googleapis.com/v1beta1/documents:analyzeSentiment?
alt=json returned "Google Cloud Natural Language API has not been used 
in project google.com:cloudsdktool before or it is disabled. Enable it 
by visiting
   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/language.googleapis.com/over
view?project=google.com:cloudsdktool then retry. If you enabled this 
API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our 
systems and retry.">
```

I think this shows that the project used: `project=google.com:cloudsdktool`

How can I change this to `project-name`?

I have enabled this api in the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone that has this issue:

One needs to set their Environment variable. If you are using virtualenvs, set the variable as follows.

In the file: `.virtualenvs/env_name/bin` edit the file activate to contain the following line:

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/abs/path/to/credentials.json
```

This credentials.json is donwloaded from the api page. Full instructions can be gathered from [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials)

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Setting the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env var didn't fix the issue in my case ... It does work in production (AppEngine) but can't run in dev ... anyone else having the same issue?

Comment: try unset your env var with `unset GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` and then try this `gcloud auth application-default login` 
Will be interesting to see whether this works.